# 2D graphics with Direct3D

Tags: 2d, directx, directx9

I'm trying to work with 2D graphics using Direct3D 9, but am not sure where to start. Right now I'm using a texture as the "draw buffer", and drawing that texture to screen. For the simplest things, it works. But I can't see a way to e.g. draw lines, arcs, and the like onto the texture. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you need Direct3D? Or is that changeable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The GDI approach:**

- Create a bitmap and a device context
- Render your 3d graphics into the bitmap using GDI
- StretchBlit the bitmap onto the texture

**The Pixel approach:**

- Lock the texture and fill the pixels using e.g. Bresenham's algorithm.

**The Render approach:**

- Use DrawPrimitiveUP with D3DPT_LINELIST or D3DPT_LINESTRIP for drawing lines.
- Arcs, circles and other curved shapes can be composited from lines.
- For filled shapes generate meshes using D3DXCreateShpere/Box/Torus etc. and render those using orthographic projection. You'd use a sphere mesh to render filled circles, a box mesh for filled rectangles and a torus would allow for curved shape outlines.

Answer (score 3):

Use Sprites in Direct3D 9. Very simple way of creating 2D objects in a 3D space.

There's a tutorial here: [Sprite Tutorial](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/sprites.html)

I've used sprites to create a 2D HUD in my 3D games and they turn out pretty well.

To draw lines, just use the D3DPT_LINELIST or D3DPT_LINESTRIP primitives with DrawPrimitive().

Drawing Arcs might be a little bit more difficult. You could look into drawing Bezier curves for that: [Bezier Curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)